# How prove $f(x)\le f(b)$. if $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere in [a,b], differentiable except at a countable number of points in [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

**QUestion:**

> let $f(x)$  is continuous everywhere in [a,b], differentiable except at a countable number of points in [a,b].and  $f'(x)\ge 0$
>
> show that
>   $$f(x)\le f(b)$$

This problem is from this: [china BBS]http://www.duodaa.com/?qa=4999/一个证明题

My idea: if $f'(x)$ is integrable,Assmue that $f(x)$ is not derivative on $x_{i},x_{i}>x_{i-1},i=1,2,3,\cdots,n$,then we have
$$0 \le \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}f'(x)dx=f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1}),i=1,2,\cdots, x_{0}=a,x_{n}=b$$
then have
$$f(b)\ge f(x)$$

But I know this methods is not true,so How prove it? Thank you

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by $f(x)$ is derivative. Do you mean it is the derivative of a differentiable function $F$?

Comment: With the assumptions, your method looks good, $f$ has to be an increasing function wherever differentiable, and continuity assures the value does not drop anywhere.

Comment: @Macavity: if the points of non-differentiability are $\{0\} \cup \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, how does one form an open interval to the right of $0$ on which to integrate?

Comment: @Carl Mummert Youre right, I considered only finitely many discontinuities.  However in your e.g. continuity at $x=0$ should assure a nbd to the right where the value is arbitrarily close to $f(0)$, and farther than that nbd the earlier argument holds. Not rigorous though :(

Comment: Yes, it is not a basic exercise. It seems to me that it will take a compactness or Baire category argument, but it's not obvious to me yet how to start it. @Macavity

Comment: @Macavity: the result would become false if we weaken the assumption to say the derivative is nonnegative except on a set of measure 0. We can make a counterexample from the Cantor staircase function.

Answer (score 0):

the function $f$ is bounded. let $x_n$ be the $n^{th}$ point of non-differentiability according to some pre-chosen numbering.
for $\epsilon \gt 0$ cover each $x_n$ with an interval $I_n = (x-\frac{\epsilon}{2^n},x+\frac{\epsilon}{2^n})$.

let $S_{\epsilon} = \bigcup_n I_n$ the total measure of $S_{\epsilon}$ is no greater that $4\epsilon$. set $T_{\epsilon}= [a,b] \backslash S_{\epsilon}$

perhaps this construction can be used?